# Node.js: is app.locals a global obj?

Tags: node.js, express

Is app.locals a global variable? IE: will it persist between users or is it safe for storing data like userId etc (instead of passing every time through the req.session obj)?

Comment: `app.locals` is shared between requests (so it can be used to store data), however its purpose is to keep data that is used in templates. Besides what are you trying to achieve? What do you mean by "passing every time through the req.session obj"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Express...

- `app` is usually the name of the variable that stores an application - object returned by `express()`
- `req` is usually the name of the param of the function that handles a specific type of request

The key difference is, obviously, the lifetime of the corresponding objects: the one stored in `req` lives as long as *particular* request is served (after that the handler function just finishes, taking all the local params - and arguments - with it), the one stored in `app` lives as long as application is working.

The bottom line - the data stored in `app.locals` is persistent between requests.