# Express.js - How to Modify app.locals variables in routes

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a node.js project.  The following code is part of my app.js file.  I'm making a query from the database and storing the results in a global variabled called 'Cats'.  I'm using this variable to display the categories on a sidebar of the site.  I don't think its relevant but I am using Jade as templating engine.

```
var app = express()

var query = "SELECT * FROM findadoc.categories";
client.execute(query, [], function(err, results) {
  if(err) {
    res.status(404).send({meg: err});
  }
  else {
    app.locals.cats = results.rows;
  }
});
```

In one of the routes, I allow the user to add additional category to the database.  What I need is for the 'apps.locals.cats' variable to get updated with the new set of categories.  Is there anyway for me to modify this in my routes?  I tried the following but it didn't work.

```
router.post('/add', function(req, res, next) {
    var cat_id = cassandra.types.uuid();
    var query = "INSERT INTO findadoc.categories(cat_id, name) VALUES (?,?)";
    client.execute(query, [cat_id, req.body.name], {prepare: true},   function(err, results) {
        if(err) {
            res.status(404).send({msg: err});
        } 
        else {
            cats = results.rows;
            req.flash('success', "Category Added");
            res.location('/doctors');
            res.redirect('/doctors');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What is `apps`? Did you mean `res.locals` and if so where are you using that, and what templating engine would be using it etc ?

Comment: apps is an instance of express.  I am using Jade as templating engine.  I updated the question with this information.

Comment: That `cats` variable in your router is definitely not the same thing as your `app.locals.cats`.

Comment: @E_net4 Is there any way to access the app.locals.cats variable in the router?    How can I modify it outside of app.js?

Comment: The [API documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html) states that you cannot access local variables in middleware. It seems to me that you are better off making a different approach to your problem that does not involve app locals.

Comment: @E_net4 You are correct.  I missed that part of the documentation.  Thank you.

Comment: @E_net4 the manual now says "Local variables are available in middleware via req.app.locals"  http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.locals

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In Express 4 You can access to `app` from `req` with `req.app`. See [Request object](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.locals) API doc.

> Locals are available in middleware via req.app.locals (see req.app)

In your middleware you could do it as this:

```
router.post('/add', function(req, res, next) {
    // do some cool stuff
    req.app.locals.cats = something;
    // more cool stuff
});
```

Comment: How do you use locals directly on the view?

Comment: You could expose data to views in res.locals: http://expressjs.com/es/api.html#res.locals

Comment: anything in req.app.locals is global to the app, for every connection. You don't want to store credentials there.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758158/node-js-is-app-locals-a-global-obj

Comment: @Carlos won't req.app.locals.cats will set the value in app locals which means this can be used directly with views !!! why would I want to set that value again in res.locals also? Can you help me with this?

Comment: @pravinpoudel sorry it's been 5 years since last time I did something with express. I don't even remember what locals were.